# Run tests from code with arg

Tags: python, pytest, fixtures

I used to run tests with a command like

```
pytest.main('-s path_to_file --my_fixtures_arg1 arg_value')
```

At the moment, such a call is considered obsolete, and you need to call this command through a list of arguments. But I can not pass the necessary parameters in any way. Who knows the solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm currently using list of arguments since passing string was deprecated. In your case I think this one should work:

```
arguments = ['-s', '--my_fixtures_arg1=arg_value', 'path_to_file']
pytest.main(args=arguments)
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently `pytest` [uses](https://github.com/pytest-dev/pytest/blob/master/_pytest/config.py#L153) `shlex.split` to split a string into a list of arguments.

You can do the same if your string comes from DB, config file or such:

```
import shlex, sys
args_list = shlex.split(args_string, posix=sys.platform != "win32")
```